# python shell shows a file with contents but they can't be loaded on disk

Tags: python, io, scripting, ipython

I am trying to use a script to write to file. I do:

```
In [15]: f = file('/home/me/scripts/python/notrecent.txt', 'w')

In [16]: f
Out[16]: <open file '/home/me/scripts/python/notrecent.txt', mode 'w' at 0x7f8677440030>

In [17]: notrecentstring
Out[17]: 'Username, "Full name", "Clinics they still work at", "Last logon"\n"jdo", "John Do", "Dallas", "08/19/2013"\n"
...yadayada'
In [18]: f.flush()

In [19]: f.write(notrecentstring)

In [20]: f
Out[20]: <open file '/home/me/scripts/python/notrecent.txt', mode 'w' at 0x7f8677440030>

In [22]: f.close()

In [23]: f = file('/home/me/scripts/python/notrecent.txt', 'r')

In [24]: content = f.read()

In [25]: content
Out[25]: 'Username, "Full name", "Clinics they still work at", "Last logon"\n"jdo", "John Do", "Dallas", "08/19/2013"\n"
...yadayada'
In [26]: f.close()
```

Yet when I load the file from its location it's completely blank. What could possibly cause such baffling behavior? Thank you

Cody

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean "when I load the file from its location" versus loading it in the python shell?

Comment: What happens if you type at your shell `cat /home/cchilders/scripts/python/notrecent.txt`.  Also, early in your example the path is `'/home/me/scripts/python/notrecent.txt'` and later it is `'/home/cchilders/scripts/python/notrecent.txt'`.  Which is it?

Comment: I mean if I click gedit and get the file (GUI open) it loads blank. If I cat I get nothing. blank

Comment: That should work (f.flush(), f.write(), f.close()). I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Check your file name, it wont throw an error if you got it wrong, it will actually just create a new .txt file with the incorrect name. You may be writing to that instead.

Comment: [me@localhost emailcleanup]$ cat notrecent.txt 
[me@localhost emailcleanup]$

Comment: I never would have expected that to be silent. lemme check

Comment: it's cchilders, I just forgot to take it out. Don't hack me lol

Comment: yes sir. I graduated 2012 though

Comment: I somehow managed to make a file of the same name in scripts/python when I meant scripts/python/emailcleanup (for my boss). Sorry guys thanks though